# How to have real paths in a static NextJS website with working imagepaths?

Tags: next.js, path, static, config

I'm trying to deploy a static NextJS website by exporting a distrbution folder which I then upload to my server.

My problem is this: if I click on a Link to another path like `'/about'` - it works. If I then **reload the page or type the url manually, it gives me a 404 Errorpage** (not even the prepared one).

I actually found something to fix this by making a `next.config.js` which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
}
```

but **THEN the images don't work anymore** on the about-Page!! It points to `'domain.com/about/images/img.jpg'` instead of `'domain.com/images/img.jpg'` where it actually is located.

There must be something to fix this, right? I think it's something obvious I just don't know and would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out now that it has to do with my server settings, and I fixed it with a .htaccess!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```